# Circle C# Mathematics

Tags: c#, math, geometry, trigonometry

Ok...this question will get complicated for most...I'm trying to figure out a formula for 2 things so i can write all of this in nearly one line of code and have it go on for as long as I'd like..

1. formula for commented sections so i can get rid of the need for i > && i < by using ratio's in some way.
2. formula for angle 2.4f, 1f, 0.6f 0.5f(probably can be more precise but...how?!

Don't need help with radius it's perfect increment of 1.2f this is probably part of the formula needed to find out the other 2 in someway?

There is so much math going on here that it is just getting a little complicated for me and I just can't figure out how to reduce it down past this point...

```
pointNum = (i * 1.0f) / 7;

if (i > 0 && i <= 6) //cannot divide by 0
{
    angle = pointNum * Mathf.PI * 2.4f;
    radius = 1.2f;
}
else if(i > 6 && i <= 20) //3.3333~
{
    angle = pointNum * Mathf.PI * 1f;
    radius = 2.4f;
}
else if(i > 20 && i <= 43) //2.15
{
    angle = pointNum * Mathf.PI * 0.6f;
    radius = 3.6f;
}
else if(i > 43 && i <= 79) //1.837209302325581
{
    angle = pointNum * Mathf.PI * 0.5f;
    radius = 4.8f;
}

float x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;//radiusX;
float z = Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius;//radiusZ;

pos = new Vector2(x, z);
```

The end result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Can you describe what your program is actually supposed to be doing? You're creating vectors based on some `i` parameter, but why?

Comment: you can tell by pointNum....it's a number of points and the reason it is divided by 7 is because well...it's the defined # that has been working from trial/error lol...all that's really being done here...is points are being created that's it.P.S. don't give me a - just because you can't understand it..that doesn't make sense at all. I said in the first sentence it may be complicated for most!

Comment: you really don't need to know programming here you only need to know math

Comment: I just feel like, if we knew what your end goal was, we would be better equipped to suggest solutions. Are you trying to lay out points on an inward-moving spiral? There are a number of simple parametric equations that could give you aesthetically pleasing results.

Comment: this is the result of the current setup:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/Leb7l.jpg
I need it to continue based on the number i feel like in this case "i". The reason I'm not understanding the -'s is if you know math you would know this is happening without needing an image right? i also don't have 10 rep so can't even post the image go figure...

Comment: ok that's weird it posted the image anyway?! ulgh don't understand stackoverflow sometimes that must be a bug lol

Comment: Thanks for providing an image :-) I've edited it into your post.

Comment: hmm, interesting, thanks!

Comment: Looks like you want a series of concentric circles, each one composed of circles whose edges touch, or are separated by some small margin. It is an interesting problem... I'm going to think about this.

Comment: Yes, basically going to be creating different formations i guess the key word here is "concentric circles"...honestly didn't even know what that word was until now! :)

Comment: it is?  c# math geometry trigonometry only 1 tag is in C#

Comment: @user2455808 If it isn't a programming question you can always post it on  [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: i don't even know where it posted i just put in tags and hit ask question haha. plus you do need to at least know an if statement and where "i" is coming from which is nearly always going to be in a for(int i=0;) statement or some kind of "index" which is why i is usually the letter used..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as OP admits and as the only answer (so far) indicates, this is not a programming question but a mathematical one.

Comment: it's not a mathematical one when it comes to performance...that is the issue here. if you use the mathematical formula directly it runs WAY slower. My temporary method clearly proves that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radius of concentric circles will be the small circle diameter plus a separation by a integer factor.

C1 Diameter  = 1 * ((2*R) + S);
C2 Diameter  = 2 * ((2*R) + S);

To know how many small circles can be created, you have to calculate the angle (green filled) that made yellow lines. This angle is easily calculated if you take the triangle made by yellow, green and blue lines.

cos = green line length / yellow line length;

green line length = C1 Diameter;

yellow line length = sqrt( blue line length * blue line length + green line length * green line length);

with the cosine you can calculate the angle with acos function.

later you can divide 360 by the angles and you get the number of circles.

of course it will not by exact, but the decimal part can by distributed among all circles.

[image]

Comment: alright! once i get through converting this to code i will post it for the programing answer version and of course say this is the answer once i verify it works! :)

Comment: Hmm while converting this...2 of the variables are a mystery to me

float r = 1.2f; //radius increment

//i is seperation?!
float C1 = 1 * ((2*r) + i);
float C2 = 2 * ((2*r) + i);

//what's blue line
float test = C1/(Mathf.Sqrt(?*?+C1*C1));

what is separation and what is blue line

Comment: `float C1 = 1 * ((2*radius) + i);
float C2 = 2 * ((2*radius) + i);

//what's blue line? is it C2?
float angle = Mathf.Acos(C1/(Mathf.Sqrt(C2*C2+C1*C1)));
float x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;
float z = Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius;`
right now what I'm getting is a line with the mini circles placed on top of each other. I am doing something wrong with the equation but know i have it mostly right.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so...Here is both methods i got part of Blau's answer translated however...the performance was already far worse just from that it turns out my way is wayyyy faster so guess doing it manually and creating ranges is going to be my only choice thanks for the information though guys.

```
void CreateConcentricCircles(int i)
    {
        //Method1
        pointNum = (float)i / 7;
        if (angleCache != pointNum * Mathf.PI)
            angleCache = pointNum * Mathf.PI;

        if (i > 0 && i <= 7) //cannot divide by 0
        {
            angle = angleCache * 2f;
            radius = 1.2f;
        }
        else if(i > 7 && i <= 21) //3.3333~
        {
            angle = angleCache * 1f;
            radius = 2.4f;
        }
        else if(i > 21 && i <= 44) //2.15
        {
            angle = angleCache * 0.6f;
            radius = 3.6f;
        }
        else if(i > 44 && i <= 72) //1.837209302325581
        {
            angle = angleCache * 0.5f;
            radius = 4.8f;
        }
        else if(i > 72 && i <= 103)
        {
            angle = angleCache * 0.45f;
            radius = 6f;
        }
        else if(i > 103 && i <= 138)
        {
            angle = angleCache * 0.4f;
            radius = 7.2f;
        }
        else if(i > 138 && i <= 151)
        {
            angle = angleCache * 0.37f;
            radius = 8.4f;
        }

        float x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;//radiusX;
        float z = Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius;//radiusZ;
        pos = new Vector2(x, z);

        //Method2

        /*if (i > 0 && i <= 6) //cannot divide by 0
            radius = 1.2f;
        else if(i > 6 && i <= 20) //3.3333~
            radius = 2.4f;
        else if(i > 20 && i <= 43) //2.15
            radius = 3.6f;
        else if(i > 43 && i <= 71) //1.837209302325581
            radius = 4.8f;
        else if(i > 71 && i <= 102)
            radius = 6f;
        else if(i > 102 && i <= 150)
            radius = 7.2f;

        float C1 = 1 * ((2*radius) + i);
        //float C2 = 2 * ((2*radius) + i);

        //what's blue line? is it C2?
        float anglex = Mathf.Sin(C1) * radius;
        float anglez = Mathf.Cos(C1) * radius;

        pos = new Vector2(anglex, anglez);*/
    }
```